# Material-design add chip when out of focus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material

I am currently using vue materials. Needs to add functionality that when the user is "focusout" the chip is automatically added like in angular materials: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

Here you can test how it works in vue materials (user have to push enter to add)

https://vuematerial.io/components/chips

There is a function in vue materials "insertChip" but I have no idea how to call it or is it possible at all?
https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/dev/src/components/MdChips/MdChips.vue

Expected effect, but any way of invoking this function will be good:

```
<md-chips
  class="md-primary" 
  @blur="insertChip"
  v-model="model">
</md-chips>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This would be on focus out of an input though, right? Like if you're typing and you hit tab or click out, it turns into a chip?

Comment: @DanOswalt
Exactly.

Comment: Hm, I had an answer written out but rereading your question, I think you'd want to extend the MDInput class and add that @blur="insertChip" functionality in there yourself. That's just a guess, your question got more complicated when I thought about it :)

Answer (score 2):

They have implemented the "Auto Insert" boolean prop in the [last months](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/commit/0930fd4fec1a241c12ae38321847cc54358a7264) (`md-auto-insert`), you can just call it like stated on the [official page](https://vuematerial.io/components/chips/):

```html
<md-chips
  class="md-primary" 
  :md-auto-insert="true"
  v-model="model">
</md-chips>
```